# Apache HttpClient throwing Exception while using Wily agent

Tags: java, monitoring, servlet-filters, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a simple filter class which connects to a different application in the same tomcat instance using Apache HttpClient. Recently to improve the performance of the Tomcat server we added few custom JVM arguments to tomcat and on of the argument is as follows

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/app/wily/Agent.jar -Dcom.wily.introscope.agentProfile=/app/wily/IntroscopeAgent_IAASTomcat.profile -Dcom.wily.introscope.agent.agentName=iaas_dev_tomcat_instance"
```

After adding this property the Apache HttpClient code does not work and throws following exception stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Socket not created by this factory.
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.isSecure(PlainSocketFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultClientRequestDirector.execute(DefaultClientRequestDirector.java:309)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:501)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:422)
    at com.vzw.issi.filters.UserValidationFilter.doFilter(UserValidationFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Following is my filter code.

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(securityServiceURL);
                // Getting the SM Header
                httpPost.setHeader(StatusReportConstants.SM_USER, httpServletRequest.getHeader(StatusReportConstants.SM_USER));
                List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusReportConstants.SOURCE_APP_NAME, StatusReportConstants.APP_DISPLAY_NAME));
                urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusReportConstants.SUB_SERVICE_NAME, StatusReportConstants.SERVICE_VALIDATE_USER));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String jsonString = null; 
                if (null != httpEntity) {
                    jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                }
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
```

I am communicating on http only. When I comment that JVM parameter this httpclient code works fine.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the agent instruments the `java.net.Socket` class which confuses older versions of HttpClient's connection management code. If you upgrade HttpClient to version 4.2.6 or 4.3.1 the problem should go away.

Comment: I will try with the latest version of HttpClient, cause I was using 4.0.1 till now, but meanwhile Can you elaborate on this issue or atleast can you point me to some info about this. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I tried with the latest version of httpclient jar i.e. 4.3.1 and it did work, so thanks a ton :)